# Number Format on Array of Int Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, number-formatting

I have an array look like these :

```
console.log(myArray);

myArray: [100000, 300000, 20000000, 3450000, 610000]
```

What I want to do is converting my array into like these:

```
myArray: [100.000, 300.000, 20.000.000, 3.450.000, 610.000]
```

So far, I've tried code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
   const element = (myArray[i]/1000).toFixed(3);
}
console.log(element);
```

But it seems didn't work at all.
Anyone can help me to solve these?

Thanks.

Comment: What's `3.450.000` supposed to be? 3 million something? 3 thousand something? 3 something?

Comment: yes, sir 3 million Imean @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: `element` is declared inside `for` loop and you are logging it outside. Use `myArray[i] = myArray[i]/1000...` inside the loop. Besides, it's not clear whether you want `.` as a thousands separator OR you are trying to divide the numbers by 1000

Comment: Literally 3 seconds away from posting my answer and this gets closed... Use Intl.NumberFormat with your locale and a decimal style.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Intl.NumberFormat` with a locale that matches your required output (e.g. German/Germany):

```js
const array = [100000, 300000, 20000000, 3450000, 610000];
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE');
const formatted = array.map(formatter.format);

console.log(formatted);
```